# Sudo doesn't work, pkexec visudo neither

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo, pkexec

When I try to run any command with `sudo` I get this:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I founded that `pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R` and `pkexec visudo` has worked for some people, but when I run any of those I get this:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

When I run `ls` in the `/etc` directory it shows many files and directories; `sudoers` and `sudoers.d` are among that list. But if I run `cd sudoers` I get `-bash: cd: /sudoers: No such file or directory`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you have done a `sudo chown -R 1000 /`. This has irrevocably trashed your system. Do what you can to save your data and reinstall.
2. It's `ls /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d`